# Use "paste" to generate function in r

Tags: r, function, formula, paste

I plan to use paste to generate a formula but I only know how to do the first half. The first half is `Surv(age, group)~x`; but how do I add on the second half which makes the final product as `Surv(age, group)~x + strata(factor(gender), bmi)`?

This is what I have at the moment and it does not work...

```
tmpfun <- function(x) as.formula(c(paste("Surv(age, group)", x , sep="~"), paste0("+ strata(factor(gender), bmi)")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass more than 2 arguments to `paste`.

```
tmpfun <- function(x) {
    as.formula(
        paste("Surv(age, group) ~", x, "+ strata(factor(gender), bmi)")
    )
}
```

Though `sprintf` might be a bit tidier.

```
tmpfun <- function(x) {
    as.formula(
        sprintf("Surv(age, group) ~ %s + strata(factor(gender), bmi)", x)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. I've just changed `paste0` place.

```
tmpfun <- function(x) as.formula(paste0(paste("Surv(age, group)", x , sep="~"), "+ strata(factor(gender), bmi)"))
```